# Reaching a 192.* device from an Airport Extreme

Tags: airport-extreme

There is an legacy IP device that has a 192.* setup, and I'm trying to reach the IP UI through a browser. I'm bridging my Airport Extreme  (2 yrs old) through the property network, which is all on the Airport 10.1.* range.  I've read that the Airport Extreme can be temporarily switched to a different IP range (192), but when I try to do this, I get a message that says "The router address you have entered is not compatible with your WAN IP address."

Steps taken in Airport Utility (El Cap)

- Switched WIRELESS > NETWORK MODE to CREATE (from BRIDGE)
- Switched NETWORK > ROUTER MODE to DHCP ONLY.
- I created a range that matches  the IP of the device

Are there additional steps to configure with ipv6?  These steps are only temporary to access the UI of the device setup.  I wont have ability to access outside internet while doing this, but Airport Extreme's setup process doesnt seem very flexible.  Would appreciate any advice the community has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

You should figure out the AirPort Extreme's IPv4 address.  You say 192.* and I would guess it is 192.168.*.* but the next set of digits is important.  Does the AirPort Extreme default to 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1?

After figuring that out, figure out another address in the same subnet.  So, if the AirPort Extreme uses 192.168.1.1, you could use 192.168.1.2

Assign that address (e.g. 192.168.1.2) to the device (e.g., a computer running a web browser) that you want to connect to the AirPort Extreme.  The best way to do that is generally to connect to the LAN port, because sometimes devices disable access from the WAN port (since LANs are generally more trustable than a WAN port which may typically be more likely to receive packets from the highly untrustable Internet).  Then go into a web browser on that device, and put in the AirPort Extreme's IPv4 address.

IPv6 addresses are different, and 192 is not a particularly special IPv6 address.  If you're dealing with the 192.168 addresses, then I expect you're using IPv4, not IPv6.

If you still need help, please be more clear.  You say "I get a message".  From where?  (What is showing the message.)

Comment: The airport extreme defaults to 10.128.66.*, so the 192.168.65.* device is out of range.  Ive been able to sniff the IP address of the device, but it doesnt open in a browser window, even when I directly connect it to the ethernet port on the mac, so Im not sure how to assign it a new IP without access to the UI.  Im actually trying to assign it a 10.186.65.* IP so it can live within the same network as everything else on the network. Is there a way to cheat it? In a perfect world, I'd just do a factory reset of the device, but I'm hoping to save that as a last resort.

Comment: The router address you have entered is not compatible with your WAN IP address." -- this message appears in the AIRPORT UTILITY when I try to modify the IP address of the router.

Comment: You need to tell the device what you want it to do, regarding which IPv4 address it should use.  (As an example, one sample way is to say "use DHCP".)  This is often done via http(s) on a LAN port, but other ways could include SSH/Telnet or even a custom application (which might use some  standard protocols behind the scenes) like the AIRPORT UTILITY.  Your latest question ("Is there a way to cheat it?") may be rather best answered by experts of the specific product, rather than people with generalized networking knowledge.  ([Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) might work better.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mess with your AirPort Extreme to do this. Leave it in bridge mode. Manually give your Mac a static IP address on the same 192.* subnet as your legacy device, and you'll be able to connect to the legacy device.

Comment: Ive given this a go, but the legacy device still doesnt open in a browser window. Ive tried w ports 80 & 8080. Are there any additional steps?